# Issue to get data from json

Tags: java, android, json

i have to parse this `json`

```
output2: [
"img data-original="http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/415.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_773297_videoThumbnail.jpg"",
"img data-original="http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/515.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_773293_videoThumbnail.jpg"",
"img data-original="http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/605.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_773279_videoThumbnail.jpg"",
"img data-original="http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/917.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_773268_videoThumbnail.jpg"",
"img data-original="http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/142.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_773267_videoThumbnail.jpg"",
"img data-original="http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/479.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_773264_videoThumbnail.jpg"",
"img data-original="http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/929.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_773266_videoThumbnail.jpg"",
"img data-original="http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/196.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_773261_videoThumbnail.jpg"",
"img data-original="http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/29.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_773262_videoThumbnail.jpg"",
"img data-original="http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/4.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_773258_videoThumbnail.jpg"",
"img data-original="http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/917.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_772171_videoThumbnail.jpg"",
"img data-original="http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/73.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_772128_videoThumbnail.jpg"",
"img data-original="http://cdn.wittytv.it/wp-content/themes/wittytv/images/witty.png""
]
```

i done json with regex expression, but i am not able to parse it in android because i don't have key:value, but `img data-original="http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/73.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_772128_videoThumbnail.jpg`

i need to get only the url...

Who can help me?

Comment: What are you trying to parse it into?  i.e. what data are you interested in, just the url?

Comment: @azurefrog i need to get only url

Comment: So treat your json like what it is, just a big list of strings, and then parse the url out afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

you have invalid json, you need something like that:

```
{"output2": [ "http://", "http://", ...]}
```

Comment: can you help me here?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47160894/issue-to-parse-json

Comment: @Sisso look, you just have an array of urls, so you should parse your json as array, e.g. to get all urls you could use JsonArray as following: `JSONArray array = jsonObj.getJSONArray("output2");`

Answer (score 0):

You would need to traverse through each element of array.
You will get a string and can work on that string to filter the data after = sign.
For example,

```
let Arr = ["img-src=www.google.com","img-src=www.microsoft.com"];
let urlArr = [];
Arr.forEach(function(elem) {  
   urlArr.push(elem.split("=")[1]);  
});  
console.log(urlArr);
```

Hope this helped.