# Issue to parse json

Tags: java, android, json

I have to parse this json:

```
{
    success: true,
    outputScenario: "Default",
    data: {
    output: [
    {
    titolo: "Lunedì 6 novembre",
    sottotitolo: "Pesanti illazioni sulla conoscenza pregressa tra Vittoria e Mattia. Una nuova conoscenza per Paolo. E...",
    date: "06/11/2017"
    },
    {
    titolo: "I vincitori di Maria Express",
    sottotitolo: "Loro sono...",
    date: "06/11/2017"
    },
    {
    titolo: "Mattia e Vittoria",
    sottotitolo: "Mattia viene messo alle strette e...",
    date: "06/11/2017"
    },
    {
    titolo: "Patto illecito? Accordo segreto? Conoscenza pregressa?",
    sottotitolo: "Mattia e Vittoria sono al centro di un vero e proprio irrisolvibile caso...",
    date: "06/11/2017"
    },
    {
    titolo: "Esterna di Mattia e Vittoria - 6 novembre",
    sottotitolo: "En plein air",
    date: "06/11/2017"
    },
    {
    titolo: "Esterna di Paolo e Giorgia - 6 novembre",
    sottotitolo: "Un primo incontro molto schietto",
    date: "06/11/2017"
    },
    {
    titolo: ""Sono fatto così"",
    sottotitolo: "Mattia è molto infastidito da alcuni commenti nei suoi riguardi",
    date: "06/11/2017"
    },
    {
    titolo: ""Occhi da gatta... morta!"",
    sottotitolo: "Tra Ester e Angela non corre buon sangue....",
    date: "06/11/2017"
    },
    {
    titolo: "Esterna di Paolo e Angela - 6 novembre",
    sottotitolo: "Caldarroste e chiarimenti",
    date: "06/11/2017"
    },
    {
    titolo: "Esterna di Paolo e Ester - 6 novembre",
    sottotitolo: "Metti una serata... "romantica"",
    date: "06/11/2017"
    },
    {
    titolo: ""Sei la persona a cui penso di più"",
    sottotitolo: "Nella prossima puntata del Trono Classico...",
    date: "05/11/2017"
    },
    {
    titolo: "Esterna inedita di Paolo e Silvia - 3 novembre",
    sottotitolo: "Un'esterna vintage!",
    date: "03/11/2017"
    }
    ],
    output2: [
    "http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/415.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_773297_videoThumbnail.jpg",
    "http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/515.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_773293_videoThumbnail.jpg",
    "http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/605.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_773279_videoThumbnail.jpg",
    "http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/917.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_773268_videoThumbnail.jpg",
    "http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/142.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_773267_videoThumbnail.jpg",
    "http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/479.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_773264_videoThumbnail.jpg",
    "http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/929.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_773266_videoThumbnail.jpg",
    "http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/196.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_773261_videoThumbnail.jpg",
    "http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/29.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_773262_videoThumbnail.jpg",
    "http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/4.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_773258_videoThumbnail.jpg",
    "http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/917.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_772171_videoThumbnail.jpg",
    "http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/73.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_772128_videoThumbnail.jpg",
    "http://cdn.wittytv.it/wp-content/themes/wittytv/images/witty.png"
    ]
    },
    stateToken: "eyJqYXIiOnsidmVyc2lvbiI6InRvdWdoLWNvb2tpZUAyLjMuMiIsInN0b3JlVHlwZSI6Ik1lbW9yeUNvb2tpZVN0b3JlIiwicmVqZWN0UHVibGljU3VmZml4ZXMiOnRydWUsImNvb2tpZXMiOltdfSwidmVyc2lvbiI6MX0=",
    cookies: [ ]
}
```

The first array `output` I am able to parse, but the second array `output2` I am not able to parse.

I show you my code:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

    // Making a request to url and getting response
    String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

    Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

    if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = null;
            try {
                jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Getting JSON Array node
            JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("output");

            // looping through All Contacts
            for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                Video video=new Video();
                String titolo = c.getString("titolo");
                String sottotitolo = c.getString("sottotitolo");
                String data = c.getString("date");
                video.setTitolo(titolo);
                video.setSottotitolo(sottotitolo);
                video.setData(data);



                videoList.add(video);
            }

            JSONArray itemArray = jsonObj.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("output2");

            for(int i=0;i<itemArray.length();i++)

            {

                String c = itemArray.getString(i);

                Log.i("Value is:::",""+c);

            }


        } catch (final JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });

        }
    }    else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        });

    }

    return null;
}
```

This `for` loop does not run:

```
for(int i=0;i<itemArray.length();i++)       
{
    String c = itemArray.getString(i);
    Log.i("Value is:::",""+c);
}
```

I get this from logcat:

> Json parsing error: No value for output2

How response from server I get only the first array and not the second... why?

Comment: It seems like this JSON isn't valid. JSON's keys must be wraped with " ". It's recommended to use a JSON validator. Google for your's

Comment: your JSON is not valid !!!

Comment: `output2` array is not in `json` format, it is invalid

Comment: do yourself a favor and start again and use: https://github.com/square/moshi

Comment: json is not valid

Answer (score 1):

Try this formatted Json String

```
{
   "success": true,
   "outputScenario": "Default",
   "data": {
      "output": [
         {
            "titolo": "Lunedì 6 novembre",
            "sottotitolo": "Pesanti illazioni sulla conoscenza pregressa tra Vittoria e Mattia. Una nuova conoscenza per Paolo. E...",
            "date": "06/11/2017"
         },
         {
            "titolo": "I vincitori di Maria Express",
            "sottotitolo": "Loro sono...",
            "date": "06/11/2017"
         }
      ],
      "output2": [
         "http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/415.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_773297_videoThumbnail.jpg",
         "http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/515.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_773293_videoThumbnail.jpg",
         "http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/605.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_773279_videoThumbnail.jpg",
         "http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/917.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_773268_videoThumbnail.jpg",
         "http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/142.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_773267_videoThumbnail.jpg",
         "http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/479.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_773264_videoThumbnail.jpg",
         "http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/929.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_773266_videoThumbnail.jpg",
         "http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/196.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_773261_videoThumbnail.jpg",
         "http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/29.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_773262_videoThumbnail.jpg",
         "http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/4.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_773258_videoThumbnail.jpg",
         "http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/917.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_772171_videoThumbnail.jpg",
         "http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/73.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_772128_videoThumbnail.jpg",
         "http://cdn.wittytv.it/wp-content/themes/wittytv/images/witty.png"
      ]
   },
   "stateToken": "eyJqYXIiOnsidmVyc2lvbiI6InRvdWdoLWNvb2tpZUAyLjMuMiIsInN0b3JlVHlwZSI6Ik1lbW9yeUNvb2tpZVN0b3JlIiwicmVqZWN0UHVibGljU3VmZml4ZXMiOnRydWUsImNvb2tpZXMiOltdfSwidmVyc2lvbiI6MX0=",
   "cookies": []
}
```

Comment: Yes , your json is not valid. Format your json properly.

Comment: why? please help me!!

Comment: where is the mistake?

Comment: In JSON ,  every key should be in double quotes. In the JSON you had posted , all the keys were normal strings without quotes. That was the error

Comment: This is your json  

    success: true, --> without quotes for key

Formatted JSON  

     "success": true, --> with quotes for key

Comment: so i need to  have "date" and no date and etc ecc

Comment: but i am able to parse array with key without double quotes...i am not able to parse the second array...server give me json with only first array no with the second...

Comment: But your Json is not formatted properly.  You can see an example here.http://json.org/example.html

Answer (score 0):

"data" object has 2 arrays - Output , output2.
 You got the first one right by pulling "output" from data . 
 Do the same way for 
 the second one.

JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("output");

Change this line

```
JSONArray itemArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("output2");
```

to

```
 JSONArray output2 = jsonObj.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("output2");
```

Comment: your observation seems correct however upon correcting as proposed, the problem is that `output2` is not a valid `json` array

Comment: Seems like the Json string that you have posted is not valid. Try checking it with a json validator online.

Comment: Error: Parse error on line 1:
{   success: true,  outp
--^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'